# Java.net.http not found on compilation despite appearing in module list

Tags: java, gradle, httpclient

When trying to compile my gradle project i receive this error:
`error: package java.net.http does not exist  import java.net.http.HttpClient;`

Similarly, `HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();` throws another error, saying HttpClient cannot be resolved to a type.

I know that this class was only implemented in Java11, but I have Java 17 installed on my system and ensured that gradle is also using Java 17.

The import is not recognized in VS Code and throws an error when compiling as mentioned above.

Oddly, when I restart VS Code and hover over the `.newHttpClient();` method call it gives me a popup showing the normal information about the method (as if it had found it), then after loading removes this hover?

On a similar thread the module did not appear in `java --list-modules`, however `java.net.http` appears in mine.

Comment: Did you add a `require java.net.http` to your module descriptor?